# Are there settings for the Sony Accessory Emulator?

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

When I am running the Sony Android Accessory Emulator on my Nexus 7, the SmartWatch 2 emulation of my watch app does not match the actual SmartWatch 2 device. The layout of the textviews on the emulator is a little different from the device. This emulator works well on the Samsung S3. Are there any emulator settings that can correct this problem?

(I realize that emulation is not always exact, but in this case I would expect it to be a little closer to the watch.)

Here is the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/screen_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/screen_height"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/screen_background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_current_location_name"
        style="@style/text_current_location_name"
        android:text="State College" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_current_location_icon"
        style="@style/img_current_location_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_current_location"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_weather_icon"
        style="@style/img_weather_icon" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_current_temperature"
        style="@style/rl_current_temperature" >
        <!-- current temperature symbol -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_temperature_symbol"
            style="@style/text_temperature_symbol"
            android:text="&#176;" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_temperature_value"
            style="@style/text_temperature_value"
            android:text="72" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_weather"
        style="@style/text_weather_short"
        android:text="Thunderstorms" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_today_temperature"
        style="@style/rl_today_temperature" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day_min_temperature_symbol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/today_temperature_font_size"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:text="&#176;" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day_min_temperature_value"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/day_min_temperature_symbol"
            style="@style/today_temperature_text"
            android:text="67" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day_temperature_divider"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/day_min_temperature_value"
            style="@style/today_temperature_text"
            android:text="/" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day_max_temperature_symbol"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/day_temperature_divider"
            style="@style/today_temperature_text"
            android:text="&#176;" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day_max_temperature_value"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/day_max_temperature_symbol"
            style="@style/today_temperature_text"
            android:text="80" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day_temperature_label"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/day_max_temperature_value"
            style="@style/today_temperature_text"
            android:text="Today: " />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_accuweather_logo"
        style="@style/img_accuweather_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_accuweather" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the layout file.

Comment: I added the layout file to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no settings to fix layouts of the emulator. It is an app at the end of the day which emulates the behaviour of the Smartwatch connecting with the other components like Smart Connect and Host app for the Smartwatch 2.  But I am curious as to what issues are you really facing. Is it more of a layout issue or is it a bug?

Comment: Seems like a layout issue. Looks fine on Samsung S3, but has text layout issues on Nexus 7. I wonder if it has something to do with a TextView using android:layout_alignParentRight="true".

Comment: I can inform this to the Emulator team. Seems like a quick fix.